# How to query mongoDB for a given date range?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose to query data for my node.js application for a given month where I accept the input for a year and month from the user.

This is what I am doing

```
var lastDay = 31
    if (month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 8 || month == 10) lastDay = 30
    else if (month == 1) lastDay = 28

var cookies = await Cookies.find({ 
        docDate: { 
            "$gte": new Date(parseInt(year), parseInt(month), 1),
            "$lte": new Date(parseInt(year), parseInt(month), lastDay)}}).sort("docDate");
```

When I try to query the db for the month of february, I am getting results only uptil the 26 Feb and the result also includes data from january.

Please help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What about leap years?

Answer (score 0):

Use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) library:

```
docDate: { 
   "$gte": moment().startOf('month').toDate(),
   "$lte": moment().endOf('month').toDate()
}
```

`moment()` is the current time. In order to input specific day, use `moment(year + '-' + month, "YYYY-MM")` for example.

Comment: Using moments is not working for me... The database returns nothing for when I use moments as moments("2021- 01")

Comment: Sorry, did a typo. Must be `moment()` (without 's'). Note, you also did a typo with `"2021- 01"`

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the date that is passed to the query.

```js
new Date(2021,01,01); --> 2021-01-31T16:00:00.000Z
new Date(Date.UTC(2021,01,01)); --> 2021-02-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

If the date field in the database is in `UTC` then try using `new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day))`